# Maximum Variance Orthogonal Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have a vector, $\textbf{z}$, which is $(n \times 1)$ and a matrix, $\textbf{A}$, which is $(n \times p)$. I want to find the linear transformation, $\textbf{w} = \textbf{A} \textbf{x}$, with the following three properties:

1. It's orthogonal to $\textbf{z}$: $\hspace{1mm}$ $\textbf{z}^\top \textbf{w} = 0$
2. It's centered: $\hspace{1mm}$ $\textbf{1}^\top \textbf{w} = 0$
3. It has the maximum variance of any vector satisfying (1) and (2).

For (3), I'm trying to maximize
$$ \frac{1}{n} \textbf{w}^\top \textbf{w} - \frac{1}{n^2} \textbf{w}^\top \textbf{1} \textbf{1}^\top \textbf{w}$$

I'm getting stuck trying to coerce the third constraint into a linear equation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $w^T 1=0$, the second summand in (3) disappears.

Comment: what is the variance of a vecotr?

Comment: I’m getting a little informal with the variance concept in applying it to a vector. But it would be defined as the difference in the two quadratic forms I showed. And yes, the second term disappears when (2) holds.

Comment: What do you call a variance here? I don't see anything stochastic here.

Comment: A "sample" variance can be defined for any given vector. That's what the formula above is calculating (using $n$ rather than the common $n-1$ in the denominator).